# When I change my httpd.conf it resets after I open usbwebserver

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I don't really know how to explain what's happening but im going to try my best.

Im doing a project, and I need to interact with my httpd.conf file. But when I open usbwebserver, the changes get reset. I'll explain it with images...

[Before I turn on UsbWebServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCvuA.png)

[After I turn on UsbWebServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lekls.png)

I really do not know what's happening since im knew to this and its my first time interacting with this.

Comment: UsbWebServer is a specific managed product, you should consult their documentation and how it all works and behaves before asking these questions I think (no disrespect intended).

Comment: I did but I didnt find anything in respect to that :S  It might be my error but I just couldnt find it :S